# How To Populate a DropDown List From a DataSet?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to populate an ASP dropdown list in vb.net with the results from a stored procedure returned in a data set. I was wondering if anyone knew the vb.net code to populate the dropdown list?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim connString As String = "Server=MYCOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=scales;Trusted_Connection=True"
    Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    myConn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select scaleName from scales", myConn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "scaleName"

    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    myConn.Close()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code that gets close to working?

Comment: I can use the sql adapter fine, but I need to use a data set now.

Comment: Please update your question with the code. Click on the Edit link just below your question to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show the data in the DropDownList control, you can use the following Code. To use the results of a Stored Procedure, you need to create the SELECT command:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim connString As String = "Server=MYCOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=scales;Trusted_Connection=True"
        Using myConn As New SqlConnection(connString)
            myConn.Open()
            Using cmd = myConn.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.uspMyStoredProc"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyInputParam", 123)
                Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(dt)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "scaleName"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.DataBind()
    End If
    ' ...
End Sub
```

I've adjusted the following things:

- Usually you only need to bind the data on the initial request. Therefore, the `if` statement at the beginning checks the `IsPostBack` property.
- In order to close and dispose the connection and the data datapter reliably, I've added some `using` statements.
- In order to access the stored procedure, I've created a SqlCommand and set the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`. The `CommandText` is set to the name of the Stored Procedure. In the sample, I've also added a parameter named `MyInputParam` that is sent to the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I know how to do it using an SqlAdapter (the databind() got cut off, sorry). I need to use the results returned from a dataset (ds) returned from a stored procedure in my business layer.

Comment: @zoltar: I've updated the sample and included details on how to call a stored procedure. Hope this helps.

Comment: I wasn't able to use the Imports System.Data.SqlClient in the ASP.NET code behind vb page (which you need to reference the SQLadapter). So I think I'll have to come up with a solution that doesn't use the SQL adapter object at all.

Comment: @zoltar: if you cannot import System.Data.SqlClient, you will not be able to use the other classes that are required to access SQL Server (e.g. SqlConnection, SqlCommand, ...). So you need to fix this first. Can you check whether your project has a reference to System.Data.dll? A missing reference to System.Data.dll is the only reason I can think of why you can't import the namespace.

Comment: Thanks Markus. Where in Visual Studio would I check that out if I have that .dll?

Comment: @zoltar: Right click on project in Solution Explorer, open Properties, tab References. Check whether System.Data is listed in the upper grid. Would be unusual though.

Comment: Thanks Markus. I got it working thanks to your help. I am fairly new to ASP.NET and thought that I needed to find another solution other than System.Data.SqlClient. When you told me that I needed to do it that way, I discovered that it was just the syntax on my import statement (duh). Thanks again for your help. I can move on with my code now.

Comment: @zoltar: good to hear that it helped. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
             IF Not IsPostback then
               PopulateDropdown()
             End IF
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateDropDown()
      Dim connString As String = "Server=MYCOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=scales;Trusted_Connection=True"
      Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(connString)
      myConn.Open()
      Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select ScaleId, scaleName from scales", myConn)
      Dim dt As New DataTable
      da.Fill(dt)

          Me.ComboBox1.DataTextField = "scaleName "
          Me.ComboBox1.DataValueField = "ScaleId"
          Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
          Me.ComboBox1.DataSourceID = String.Empty
          Me.ComboBox1.DataBind()

     myConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I already know how to do it with the SqlAdapter (the databind() got cut off, sorry). I need to use the results returned in a data set from an stored procedure returned from my business layer.